# Spring DataSource with Postgresql not able to save an object

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring boot`, `spring Datasource` and `postgresql`, my problem is am not able to save the object into DB. And table name and column names are in camel case.

Property file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/encoderDb
spring.datasource.initialize=true  spring.datasource.username=user spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl 

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"TableEncoder\"")
public class TableEncoder implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"encoderId\"")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer encoderId;

    @Column(name="\"aspectRatio\"")
    private String aspectRatio;

    @Column(name="\"audioBitRate\"")
    private Integer audioBitRate; 
}
```

Error:

```
2018-01-31 18:40:12.179 WARN 32163 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703 2018-01-31 18:40:12.179 ERROR 32163 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : The column name "encoderId" was not found in this ResultSet.
```

Note that, i can delete and list the data form the same table except save.

Comment: Try to turn on the Hibernate SQL query logging, so you can see what select query result is missing the `encoderId` column.

Comment: i tried that ,  didn't get anything from that, the thing is in entity class, if i changed  @Column(name="\"encoderId\"") to @Column(name="encoderId"), then it will work. but on the same time select query won't work.